# How to pass a method to timeit in python?

Tags: python-2.7, timeit

So I am working on comparing the iterative and recursive ways of finding fibonacci numbers.  I wanted to pass them both into timeit, but am having trouble formatting my calls to timeit.  Good someone give me a little guidance please?  Thanks!

```
    import timeit

def it_fib(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        total += n
        n -= 1
    return total

def rec_fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + rec_fib(n-1)

#print (it_fib(10))
#print (rec_fib(10))

print timeit.timeit("it_fib(n)", number = 1000000)
print timeit.timeit("rec_fib(n)", number = 1000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeit.timeit` can take a function or a string. For script use, the function is usually more convenient:

```
print timeit.timeit(lambda: it_fib(10))
print timeit.timeit(lambda: rec_fib(10))
```